# Edit 2 rows into 2 columns in a single result SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
WorkID    WorkDesc
--------------------
1         ABCD
2         DEFG
3         HIJK
```

then I've the following table as the detail of table one:

```
WorkDetailID    WorkID     WorkDetailDesc
-----------------------------------------
1               1          001
2               1          002
3               2          006
4               2          007
5               3          015
```

Each WorkID is always have maximum 2 records and minimum is 1.
I want to have the following result:

```
WorkID    WorkDesc    WorkDetailID1      WorkDetailID2
-------------------------------------------------------
1         ABCD        1                  2
2         DEFG        3                  4
3         HIJK        5                  null
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot`.  I prefer conditional aggregation.  In either case, you need a column for the pivoting.  `row_number()` to the rescue:

```
select t1.workid, t1.workdesc, 
       max(case when t2.seqnum = 1 then t2.workdetailid end) as workdetailid1,
       max(case when t2.seqnum = 2 then t2.workdetailid end) as workdetailid2
from t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t2.workid order by t2.workdetailid) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.workid = t2.workid
group by t1.workid, t1.workdesc
```

Comment: This is so great!